# GTK# toolbox is empty on Visual Studio 2019 on the MAC

Tags: macos, mono, visual-studio-2019, gtk2

Installed Visual Studio Community on MAC machine. 
Created GTK# 2.0 project. I am not able to see toolbox for designing UI. 
Toolbox showing There are no tools available for the current document.

Comment: I'm running the same issue, I'm trying by clicking the 'plus' sign at the top right of the toolbox panel to see if that fixes the problem, but it looks like the process will take ages :'(

Comment: No vail, calling the components search didn't work, so, don't waste your time doing that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's **fixed** but **not released** yet: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/659550/gtk-toolbox-is-empty-on-visual-studio-community-20.html